# How to access wildfly's admin console page from netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, deployment, wildfly

I've switched from Glassfish to Wildfly application server recently. 
I've configured Wildfly 8.2 successfully and I can deploy my applications, through Wildfly's admin console, without any problem. Anyway, I've chosen Netbeans 8.02 as my development IDE and Now I have a problem with application deployment from Netbeans. By the way, I can start and stop Wildfly server from Netbeans but when I want to go to admin console page from Netbeans, it starts browser and sets address to http://localhost:8580/console while Wildfly's welcome screen is on port 8080 and administration console on port 9090!
I think this is the cause of application deployment failure!
Could anyone help me how I can manage this problem?!
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried port 9090? By default it should be available at http://localhost:9990/console.

Comment: Yes. I have no problem with direct access to console from web browser!. Something that is bothering is Netbeans! I can't access WildFly's admin console from "Services" window in Netbeans! Right clicking on wildfly server and pressing "View Admin Console" from context menu, opens an browser with http://localhost:8580/console as URL address! Now, Which configuration file should be changed to replace 8580 with 9090?!